# Why if/else vs. or/exit in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, fopen, exit

Seeing the `exit()` [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) got me thinking:

```
$filename = '/path/to/data-file';
$file = fopen($filename, 'r')
or exit("unable to open file ($filename)");
```

Couple questions:

1. What are common use cases besides opening files for using `exit()`?
2. Since not every function everyone ever writes ends in `exit()`, how do you know to use it in some contexts vs. others?
3. Are `if/else` and `or/exit` interchangeable?

Comment: They used `or exit` because you are looking at an example for `exit`.

Comment: @Gumbo, i edited my question to remove the non-sensical part of question#3 to which you reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that context, the `or` in that statement is one of PHP's [logical operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) which when used like that, will execute the second statement if *and only if* the first one fails due to [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Since `fopen` returned false, the `or exit` statement gets executed since the first part failed.

To understand it better, here is a quick explanation of short-circuit evaluation.

```
$x = 5;
$y = 42;

if ($x == 5 or $y == 42) {
    echo "x or y is true";
}
```

In the above code, the expression `$y == 42` is never evaluated because there is no need since the first expression was true.

In that example, they are using the same logic for deciding whether or not to evaluate the statement that calls `exit`.

To address your questions:

1. I wouldn't use exit when opening a file failed unless the program was very specific.  The better thing to do would be to log an error and then return the error to the caller so they can decide what to do.
2. When to use `exit` completely depends on the code you are writing.
3. Given the explanation about short-circuiting, yes they are interchangeable in that sense.  Using `or exit` is just a bit shorter than using `if/else`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

1. CLI scripts, exit can take an integer parameter which is fed back to the console to indicate success or some form of error
2. I'm not inclined to use `exit()` or `die()` in application code, since exceptions are preferred. However, I personally think you might be overcomplicating things a little bit... it kills script execution, so use it when you need to kill a script. Truthfully I mostly only ever kill scripts mid-execution when debugging (one-off breakpoints) and that's not ideal either (again exceptions do a better job).
3. The use of `or` is mostly convenient. Here's an interesting point though...

Why does

```
$resource = mysql_connect() || die('dead')
```

not work?

The answer is that the `=` operator takes precedence over `or` so that the assignment is made first like so: `($resource = mysql_connect()) or die()`. In this way its exactly like doing an `if(!($resource = mysql_connnect())) { die() }`

Answer (score 2):

I tend to avoid using `exit()` at all as it's a really ugly way to handle errors from the user's perspective.

If you must use it, any non recoverable error would be a candidate. For example, database query or connection failures, or remote request failures.

`if/else` is equivalent to `...or whatever()`. It's just a style thing, with the latter form being more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you use `exit` in a situation where your code cannot continue if the function you were doing failed.  For example reading a file that is needed.

Comment: According to manual `"die — Equivalent to exit"`. While `exit` description:

`Terminates execution of the script. Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called.`